# UIGestureRecognizer not detected on subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I made a UIView subclass and added a circle view on top right corner of the view.  Then I added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the circle view.

The problem is that gesture is only recognized on left bottom part of circle where the circle is located over the super view.

How can I make entire circle to property detected gesture?

[image]

Following is entire class code of UIView subclass I made.

```
import UIKit

class ResizableImageView: UIView {


private let circleWidth: CGFloat = 40

var themeColor: UIColor = UIColor.magentaColor()

lazy var cornerCircle: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()

    v.layer.cornerRadius = self.circleWidth / 2
    v.layer.borderWidth  = 1
    v.layer.borderColor  = self.themeColor.CGColor

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTouchMoved) )
    v.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    return v
}()





// Init

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupSubviews()
    configureSelf()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



func setupSubviews() {

    // Add cornerButton to self and set auto layout
    addSubview( cornerCircle )
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(\(circleWidth))]", views: cornerCircle) // Extension code for setting auto layout
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(\(circleWidth))]", views: cornerCircle)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerCircle, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerCircle, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


}

func configureSelf() {

    // Set border
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = themeColor.CGColor
}




// Gesture Event

func buttonTouchMoved(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)
    print(point)

}


}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewCheckController: UIViewController {

let imageView: ResizableImageView = {
    let iv = ResizableImageView()
    return iv
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "ImageViewCheck"

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    setupSubviews()
}

func setupSubviews() {
    view.addSubview( imageView )

    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-100-[v0(200)]", views: imageView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-50-[v0(100)]", views: imageView)

}

}
```

Comment: show the code where you create the button in controller class

Comment: I added ViewController class code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, there is no touch on a subview outside the bounds of its superview.

To change this, you will have to override `hitTest(point:withEvent:)` on the superview to alter the way hit-testing works:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, withEvent:e) {
        return result
    }
    for sub in self.subviews.reverse() {
        let pt = self.convertPoint(point, toView:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, withEvent:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```